# Enable SVG overflow

Tags: javascript, reactjs, d3.js, svg

Since `overflow` for svg seems to be not yet supported, I'm asking the community what tricks and workarounds there might be to acheieve this.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/overflow

What needs to be done

- I have two `svg`s stacked, one for chart itself and one at the bottom for x axis. I need to put an element (an icon) in between those `svg`s, which will be drawn from x axis `svg`.

The culprit

- I cannot create a parent `svg` to wrap those two `svg`s and have the icon visible since the
  chart I'm dealing with has many pieces that would break due to
  complexity of the chart/ business logics

Any tips would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You may need use `<g></g>` instead of `<svg>`.

Comment: it's only the attribute that is not supported. Writing it as a property should work just fine... Try: `style="overflow: visible" `